# VBA - How to apply a script in a range only for rows that contain a specific value

Tags: excel, vba

Here goes, i have this vba script that will change the value of a cell to a 1 and change the color of the cell and the font to light green when i click on it. I have a calendar for each week of the year and each entry is divided into planning and load, i want my script to work only on the rows that are made for planning (There will be new data added to it later so i can't specify each row one by one).

Here's how the script looks for now but i have to specify which row i want to apply it to :

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F2:BE2")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value = 1 Then
            Target.Value = ""
            Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        Else
            Target.Value = 1
            Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 35
            Target.Font.ColorIndex = 35
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

In this case the row 2 is one of the rows made for planning and by clicking on the cells from F to BE the value is put to 1 and the color of the cell and the font is changed to light green. I have a formula that divides the load into how many weeks of the planning i've activated.

Here's a simple example of what i want it to do :

[image: Simple example]

Thanks for the help !

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-information-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f?

Comment: I'm trying to make a tool for a manager for capacity planning, the highlight is just to look pretty and my script already does that. I just want to have my script work on any line where it's written "Planning" and not on the lines where it's written "Load". Right now for my script to work i have to tell the exact range with the row and column but since there will be new data added to the table later on i can't have him make changes to the script everytime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't quite understand the logic around the format, but the following code should get you started.

Read the comments and adjust the ranges and text to fit your needs.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    
    ' Range that you're going to monitor
    Dim targetRange As Range
    Set targetRange = Me.Range("D2:BE10")
    
    ' Column that has keyword
    Dim keyColumn As String
    keyColumn = "B"
    
    ' Text in key column
    Dim keyText As String
    keyText = "Planning"
    
    ' Just for one cell
    If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Just in monitored range
    If Intersect(Target, targetRange) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        
    ' Just if key column has specific text
    If Not Me.Cells(Target.Row, keyColumn).Value2 = keyText Then Exit Sub
        
    ' Do other stuff
    If Target.Value = 1 Then
        Target.Value = ""
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
    Else
        Target.Value = 1
        Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 35
        Target.Font.ColorIndex = 35
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Let me know if it workds

Comment: Man thank you, i will have to tweak it a bit to work on my tool but it's working perfectly on the little example i showed even after i added new data ! That's exactly what i needed !